# How to get column name based on condition

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot, presto, unpivot

I have the following query that checks if columns are null

```
select 
    sum(case when Column_1 is null then 1 else 0 end) as Column_1, 
    sum(case when Column_2 is null then 1 else 0 end) as Column_2, 
    sum(case when Column_3 is null then 1 else 0 end) as Column_3,
from TestTable
```

It gives:

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
0         1         0
```

I want to get the column names that have null values 
So my desired out put is:

```
Column_1
Column_3
```

How can I do that in Presto? It doesn't seem easy to get as out put column name returned from query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want your results on separate row rather than in a concatenated string.

If so, you can unpivot your existing resultset with `unnest()` and arrays;

```
select t2.key
from (
    select 
        sum(case when Column_1 is null then 1 else 0 end) as Column_1, 
        sum(case when Column_2 is null then 1 else 0 end) as Column_2, 
        sum(case when Column_3 is null then 1 else 0 end) as Column_3
    from TestTable 
) t1
cross join unnest(
    array['Column1', 'Column_2', 'Column_3'],
    array[Column1, Column_2, Column_3]
) t2 (key, value)
where t2.value = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
select (case when count(column_1) <> count(*) then 'Column_1;' else '' end) ||
       (case when count(column_2) <> count(*) then 'Column_2;' else '' end) ||
       (case when count(column_3) <> count(*) then 'Column_3;' else '' end)
from TestTable  ;
```

Comment: not sure I understand that query? count(column_1)<>count(*) ? What happens if the table is empty?

Comment: @HaloKu . . . Interesting question.  Then both counts will be `0` and the column will (correctly) not be identified as having `NULL` values.

Comment: thx. in terms of performance. if I have 50 columns. Does it execute 50 times count(*) ? or this is something that is evaluated just once for all cases?

Comment: @Haloku . . . It doesn't matter.  `count(*)` is not the expensive part of the query; reading the data is.  I would hope that Presto would be among the databases that only executed it once.